# Prime generator: Good place for singleton?

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm writing a library of math functions.  One of my most basic, and commonly used, functions generates a list of prime numbers below n.  I'm trying to choose the interface to this function.  I want to avoid unnecessary computation and unnecessary copying, and I'd like a nice clean interface.  First, I considered the following:

**Singleton: return a const reference to a local static vector**

```
const std::vector<int>& getPrimesBelow(int n)
{
    static std::vector<int> primes;
    static int limit = 0;

    // Need to initialize, or resize, the prime list
    if(n > limit)
    {
        // ... add primes to list as necessary ...
        limit = n;
    }
    return primes;
}
```

**Pros:**

1. We only create one list and never have to copy it--IF the client uses our interface correctly: `const std::vector<int>& primes = getPrimesBelow(n)`
2. We may eliminate unnecessary computation if, say, clients happen to make multiple calls to `getPrimesBelow(1000000)`

**Cons:**

1. If client doesn't assign the return value into a reference, we will
   end up copying our list anyway: `std::vector<int> makesCopy = getPrimesBelow(n)`
2. If we call `const std::vector<int>& firstList = getPrimesBelow(1000)`, then later call `getPrimesBelow(1000000)`, we may break code:

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<firstList.size(); ++i)
   {
       // Unexpectedly looping over way more primes
   }
   ```

In particular, con #2 feels too evil to allow.  So, perhaps a better option is:

**Return a copy**

```
std::vector<int> getPrimesBelow(int n)
{
    static std::vector<int> masterPrimes;
    static int limit = 0; // limit for masterPrimes
    if(n > limit)
    {
        // add to masterPrimes as necessary 
    }
    // std::copy primes into return value
}
```

**Pros**

1. Still avoids unnecessary recomputation of primes.
2. Return value will never unexpectedly expand.

**Cons**

1. Will cause multiple copies of the prime list to exist in memory.  This is especially annoying in the common case where we only request a prime list once.

A third approach: 
**Return a `std::pair<>` of iterators**

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator > 
getPrimesBelow(int n)
{
    static std::vector<int> masterPrimes;
    static int limit = 0; // limit for masterPrimes
    if(n > limit)
    {
        // add to masterPrimes as necessary
        limit = n;
    }
    return std::make_pair(masterPrimes.begin(),
                          masterPrimes.lower_bound(masterPrimes.begin(), masterPrimes.end(), n))
}
```

This last approach seems to solve all the cons I listed above.  But, it has an ugly function signature and calling syntax.

Which approach to prefer, and why?

Comment: Prefer? This should be closed as opinion based. Flagged.

Comment: You are right about option 1. It is off the table. Iterator access to a cache of expensive to compute objects seems to make sense... What you really need to know is what the usage pattern looks like.

Comment: The best approach depends on what client code should look like. What kind of subsequent operations will client code perform with the prime numbers?

Comment: One con not mentioned: existing iterators will be invalidated if another call ends up increasing the size of the static vector. This is a problem in both the reference and iterator versions.

Comment: @MarkRansom doh, very good point.  I suppose this means we must scrap the iterator version?

Comment: @DanielAmaya: Why do you think a "preference" implies an "opinion"? There can be perfectly objective reasons to prefer one approach to another.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom iterator class. You'd use it something like this:

```
for (prime_iterator p = prime_iterator(), end = prime_iterator(1000000); p != end; ++p)
    // do something with *p
```

This encapsulates the access to the static prime table and prevents problems. It's also a very simple interface.

The implementation would go something like this:

```
class prime_iterator
{
public:
    prime_iterator() { m_index = 0; }
    prime_iterator(int n)
    {
        if (!m_table.empty() && n <= m_table.back())
        {
            std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::upper_bound(m_table.begin(), m_table.end(), n);
            m_index = it - table.begin();
        }
        else
        {
            extend_prime_table(n);
            m_index = m_table.size();
        }
    }
    int operator*() const { return m_table[m_index]; }  // optionally throw an exception if m_index is out of bounds
    prime_iterator & operator++() { ++m_index; return *this; }
    bool operator==(const prime_iterator & pi) const { return m_index == pi.m_index; }
private:
    void extend_prime_table(int n);

    size_t m_index;
    static std::vector<int> m_table;
};
```

**Edit:** This was such an interesting problem that I decided to flesh it out and make a working prime number generator. Rather than keeping a table of primes, I kept a boolean vector of all the odd numbers so that I could implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) directly on it. This made `operator++` a little more complex but I think it was worth it.

The `end` iterator was a little tricky to implement as well. Since the `end` iterator is supposed to point to the next value past the end of the sequence, doing it properly would have required it to contain the next prime number after the maximum one you asked for. This is impractical. I decided instead to make it contain a maximum attainable value, and to modify `operator==` so that any iterator greater than or equal to the max would compare equal.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

class prime_iterator
{
public:
    prime_iterator() : m_next(2), m_max(INT_MAX)
    {
    }
    prime_iterator(int n) : m_next(INT_MAX), m_max(n)
    {
        if ((size_t)n/2 >= m_sieve.size())
        {
            int base = (int) sqrt((double)n);
            prime_iterator end(base);
            m_sieve.resize(n/2 + 1, true);
            prime_iterator p;
            for (++p;  p != end;  ++p)
            {
                int first = std::max(*p, (base + *p - 1) / *p);
                first = (first & ~1) + 1;
                for (int i = first * *p;  i <= n;  i += 2 * *p)
                {
                    m_sieve[i/2] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int operator*() const
    {
        assert((size_t)m_next/2 < m_sieve.size() && m_sieve[m_next/2]);
        return m_next;
    }
    prime_iterator & operator++()
    {
        size_t i, end = m_sieve.size();
        for (i = (m_next - 1)/2 + 1;  i < end && !m_sieve[i];  ++i)
            ;
        m_next = i*2 + 1;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const prime_iterator & pi) const
    {
        return m_next == pi.m_next || m_next > pi.m_max || pi.m_next > m_max;
    }
    bool operator!=(const prime_iterator & pi) const
    {
        return !operator==(pi);
    }
private:
    int m_next;
    int m_max;

    static std::vector<bool> m_sieve;
};

//                          0/1    2/3   5     7     9
static bool sieve_init[] = {false, true, true, true, false};
std::vector<bool> prime_iterator::m_sieve = std::vector<bool>(sieve_init, sieve_init + sizeof(sieve_init) / sizeof(sieve_init[0]));

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (prime_iterator p, end = prime_iterator(1000);  p != end;  ++p)
        std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the results at http://ideone.com/47QbXW

Comment: Sorry to keep editing this, but I keep thinking of improvements and corrections.